# How to make the image take up whole space?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website and I want to give an image in the header part.This is my code in the HTML file

```
<header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-12">
                    <h1>Tourister</h1>
                    <p style="padding:40px"></p>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best 
                        touring experiences, and create a unique experience. You will surely be surprised by our amazing offers and deals we
                        provide throughout the year !
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

And I have used this code in the CSS file.

```
.jumbotron
{
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #7986cb;
color: floralwhite;     
background-image: url("../img/image6.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Now the problem is that my image is not taking up the entire height and width of the jumbotron as in the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd9T4.png)

I want it to take up the entire space.I have used images of different sizes but it's of no use.None is taking the entire space of the window.
So any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

N.B.: I have read other questions of images not taking the entire width in stack overflow but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I'm not entirely sure that you want to apply the class (or could be an ID) to the header as opposed to one of the lesser divs. Might depend on what else you've got going.

```
.jumbotron 
{
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #7986cb;
color: floralwhite;     
background-image: url("../img/image6.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Seeing the other answers: It will also depend on characteristics of your image and what kind of display you prefer. Cover != 100% x 100% != Contain. See [CSS3 background-size Property "Try-It"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover).

Comment: Ok.One thing what was the meaning of your last line?Cover not equal to 100%? can you explain please?

Comment: Try the Try-It thing linked - it's easier to see the difference between the different ways of filling the space than to explain it - but 100%x100% will distort image to fill completely, "cover" will preserve image proportions (in effect crop image) but fill whole space, "contain" will preserve proportions and fill either by height or width (which might = 100% x 100% if proportions of space are constant and same as image)

Answer (score 3):

The property you're looking for is `background-size`.

Add this to your code

```
.jumbotron {
  ...
  background-size: cover; /* Can also be "contain" */
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to add `background-size: cover` to your CSS on the `.jumbotron` class. This will insure that the background image is always the full size of the element with out distorting the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
.jumbotron {
background-image: url("../img/image6.jpg");
color: white;
background-attachment:fixed;
min-height:400px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:8px; }
```

Comment: This will just fix the background image, not stretch it to fill the background.

Comment: Sorry.But the image starts to repeat itself.

Answer (score 1):

add `background-size` property `cover` to jumbotron

```
.jumbotron{
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-size: cover;
```

`contain` will leave space unless the image has the same aspect ratio as the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css property: 
background-size:cover;

see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbLyRp

```
.jumbotron
{
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #7986cb;
color: floralwhite;     
background-image: url("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/08/24/12/54/banner-904889_960_720.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and with a 563 kb size image it does your work fine .you should use big size image fo this or use

```
   background-size:cover; in your css
```